# how to downcast a list of objects without using a function

Tags: oop, common-lisp

I got a list of Objects of class-type B (B inherits from A).
How can I downcast all the B-objects to A-objects without using a function to pull the needed information and create a new instance?

```
(defclass A () ( (varI :initarg :varI :accessor varI) ) )

(defclass B (A) ( (varII :initarg :varII :accessor varII) ) )

(defun generate-list-of-type-B-objects () (....does...some..stuff....))

(defvar *listoftypeA* (generate-list-of-type-B-objects) )
```

(I know this example is easy to rewrite, as I could make the method generate a list of type A objects, but the function is used somewhere else where type-B objects are needed, and I do not want to duplicate code)

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Lisp? Your class declarations are wrong. Common Lisp does not treat classes as types as you think. There is also no such thing as 'downcasting' in Common Lisp. The Common Lisp Object System (CLOS) works differently than the object system in languages like C++ or Java.

Comment: i am sure that i do, but I am just learing lisp and therefore used to the C++/Java type of OOP, if there is no way but to write a "casting-function" please post it and I will be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: I hoped of beeing able to somehow say that a certain object should be treated as if it where of its super-class type and therefore doesn't have the (uneeded) other member-vars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must convert your instances of class B into instances of class A, you can do a one-way conversion of them with the use of [CHANGE-CLASS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_chg_cl.htm). This is a non-reversible change of each instance.

Since I am not 100% sure what you actually want, the best suggestion I can give is "have you tried leaving them as class B and see if it works?"

Chances are that it will just work, unless you have methods of a generic function somewhere that treat instances of class B differently than instances of class A. If it's only about dropping the space that the extra slot would take, have you measured that it's actually worth it (it probably isn't, unless you have several thousands of instances of class B, where you could get by with instances of class A).

Comment: well it would work, but there will be unnecessary data and a print method will print too much as it makes use of the CALL-NEXT-METHOD feature.